# Who calls Present() (if anyone) when using Steam's OpenVR?

Tags: directx, directx-11, virtual-reality, openvr

I'm new with both directx and openvr, and trying to wrap my head around how the OpenVR compositor API works. The docs call for rendering each eye and handing each one to the compositor via Submit(). But I'm a bit confused about how Present() factors in to this flow. I expected to need to call Present() to render each eye, but from examining some existing VR games, this doesn't happen. Present is called to render any view on the main (non-VR) monitor, but is not called at all for the stuff drawn by the compositor.

Does somebody else call Present() or something lower-level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Present is to display in a traditional swap chain in a window on your screen. Because with VR, you use an alternative mechanisum and API to present the image to the HMD, you do not need a Present at all.

You only need one if you want to display a copy or anything else on the monitor along side the hmd.